# Parsing through XML returned by web service with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, web-services, parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML file returned by a webservice with jQuery. Here is the code I have set up, but nothing seems to happen.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.sample.com/webservice',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml){
        console.log(xml);
        $(xml).find('movies').each(function(){
            $(this).find('movie').each(function(){
                var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
                $('div#lat-info').html('<p>' + lat + '</p>');           
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The webservice does not explicitly create a file with '.xml' at the end that I can reference. I must reference the URL to the webservice.

Comment: Well I can't put it in any better words. Nothing really happens. I threw a few console.log() statements in there to see what was being fired, and the success function definitely wasn't.

Comment: @bob: try passing an `error` callback and see if that gets called. Try looking at the request going out in Fiddler/Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You can't request XML cross-domain. It's a security issue.

To quote from http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080904014758AAyishS

"If you have access to server-side scripting, you can attempt to do a file-read of the remote file, and process it locally... which, however, depending on your host may have been disabled, as it lends itself for abuse."